# How to setup a method call inside another method call to return different results

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a method similar to the following:

```
public List<Item> MethodA() {
    List<Things> result1 = MethodB(param1);
    if(result1==null)
        //Do Something

    List<Things> result2 = MethodB(param2);

    //Do Something 
}
```

I tried mocking this method, using Moq, for unit testing as below:

```
//Mocking the call to MethodB to return null the second time it's called
mockService.SetupSequence(x=>x.MethodB(It.IsAny<List<Things>>()))
.Returns(GetList())
.Returns(null);

//Call to method A to run the test
MethodA();
```

However this doesn't seem to work and I get only the list as the returned result for MethodB after mocking. However, I want the list to be returned in the first call and null in the second call. Any pointers/thoughts/ideas how to achieve it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mocking things on the same class you're testing, make sure you use CallBase() on the method you want to actually run, or else the mock won't run the code.

`mockService.Setup(x => x.MethodA()).CallBase();`

When I tried to run your example with MethodA set to CallBase, I got the results I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get rid of the second .Returns(null) call, by default it returns null if sequence is not specified.

Working example:

```
public class UnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
        serviceMock.SetupSequence(s => s.MethodB(It.IsAny<List<object>>()))
            .Returns(new List<int>());

        var service = serviceMock.Object;
        Assert.NotNull(service.MethodB(new List<object>()));
        Assert.Null(service.MethodB(new List<object>()));
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    List<int> MethodB(List<object> objects);
}
```